# Laravel Newsletter package error: trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Tags: laravel, mailchimp, newsletter

hope everyone is well!

I have recently encountered a problem when trying to implement a newsletter system using the Spatie newsletter package for Laravel, during the testing it was showing that I had an error in my code right in this line:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate(['email' => 'required|email']);

        if(! Newsletter::isSubscribed($request->email))
        {
            Newsletter::subscribePending($request->email);

            return back()->with('successMail', 'Check your inbox to verify your subscription to my newsletter!');

        }

        return back()->with('failureMail', 'You are already subbed.');
    }
```

It says that the error is in the line 5

`if(! Newsletter::isSubscribed($request->email))`

So I assumed the error was within the request, any help?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am not sure if I'm supposed to edit my original post or not but I have found the solution and I know why the code did not work.

The problem was within the package's config file, spatie/laravel-newsletter/config/newsletter.php

`"ssl" => true,`

The SSL value was true, while I was testing on my local server, where I only have the HTTP version allowed. Which made the request of the email that was being sent not allowed due to the fact it is an HTTP request, and by default the package requires an HTTPs request.

This is a quick fix:

`"ssl" => false,`

I do NOT recommand to use this on a server with an HTTPs connection enabled, only use this method for testing purposes in your localserver, once you decide to deploy, return the line back to true.

`"ssl" => true,`